# Missing Reporting Server templates in Visual Studio 2013 + Business Intelligence SSDT

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2014

The other day I have installed [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=42313)  (SSDT: Replacement for BIDS) and started using reporting features in **VS2013**.

Successfully created a project using *Report Server Project Wizard* template.

However, later on I needed SQL Server 2014, then I downloaded and installed the developer edition. (in case if this might've caused the problem)

Now the **Report Server Project** templates are missing from **VS2013** and I can't simply bring them back.

Now my **VS2008** has the features that I want:
[image]

But no trace of them in **VS2013 Professional**:
[image]

Any suggestions?

### Additional unsuccessful approaches I have taken

- Repaired SQL Server Data Services.
- Attempted to Uninstall this service, which led to so many problems including, can't install this service back since all the boxes are ticked and grayed out in the installation process and can't past this level anymore.
- Attempted to remove all the related components which may let me reinstall the SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013 again but didn't help. This is the Microsoft guide I took to do so:[Removing SQL Server Data Tools Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj542427%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
- Repaired the whole SQL Server 2014 (64-bit) installation from the installation medium.
- Tried retrieving unregistered VS2013 templates using `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` following this Microsoft guide [/InstallVSTemplates (devenv.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have eventually fixed my issue by following Graham's suggestion on my question on his post [Installing SQL Server Data Tools – Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](http://picnicerror.net/development/sql-server/installing-sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-03-13/) by taking *scorch earth* approach and uninstalling  every single edition of SQL that I had on my PC. The whole thing basically boils down to these three simple steps,

1. Uninstall every SQL Server instance from your PC using *Programs and Features* in *Control Panel*
2. Installed 32-bit edition of **SQL Server 2014 Express** (any other variation would work)
3. Installing 32-bit **SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013** and choosing *Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server* since the 32-bit versions match. If you got mismatch editions follow the post mentioned above.  (there is no 64-bit variation for SSDT-BI since Visual Studio is also only available in 32-bit.)

Viola,

[image]