# SSRS missing in Visual Studio 2015 (community & enterprise trial version) template

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I tried to solve my problem by using community and enterprise (trial) version of Visual Studio 2015. Couldn't solve it. Hope somebody can help me.

I want to generate a report by using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). In some tutorial I see there are SSAS, SSRS & SSIS under templates | Business Intelligence when a new project is opened in Visual Studio. In my case, I don't see it as shown in the following picture:

[image]

If I check (my OS is Windows 10 64 bit) System Settings | System | App & features, I see SQL Server Data Tools 2015 is installed (strangely I have 2 SSDT) as seen in below.

[image]

I see similar problem ([Missing Reporting Server templates in Visual Studio 2013 + Business Intelligence SSDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924984/missing-reporting-server-templates-in-visual-studio-2013-business-intelligence)) for VS2013, in which the reporter has used 32 bit SSDT tools. Is this valid for VS2015 also? What I should do for VS2015?

Comment: I ran into the same issue when trying to check the SSDT and VS2015. Uninstall VS Comunity (Community version is not compatible with SSDT) Install Professional trial version, go to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) and download the correct version for your VS2015 and SQL SERVER then just install it.

Comment: Should I install the following ?
A.  "CTP 3.3 version of SQL Server 2016"  as SQL server                              
B.  "Download the Latest SSDT Preview for Visual Studio 2015" as SSDT 
C.  VS2015 professional trial version
I tried previously but I had the same result. Could you tell me the version, download address and the order of installation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I develop the SSRS and SSIS project in Visual studio 2012 and When i open it on visual Studio 2015. both project is not loaded. then I download the SSDT and updated Its start Working

**I think this Link help You to find out Your Solution**

[ssdt bi for the visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35908453/3907534) stack over flow Answer

Answer (score 1):

Install sql server enterprise or business intelligence ctp 3.3, install VS2015 professional and finally install the latest SSDT.

1. Uninstall previous SSDT installations.
2. Download [SQL SERVER](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2016).
3. In Visual Studio go to `Extensions and Updates` and look for SQL SERVER DATA TOOLING. If the update doesn't appear, go to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/mt429383) in the third point, download the setup for your regional settings.

If it doesn't work tell use what is the exact VS2015 version.

Comment: I have working enterprise version of VS2015 but right SQL server and SSDT needed to install. Looks there are several version for these, I am not an expert, so I am looping as before. Can you point exact version and URL from where find the matching one.