# SSDT-BI For the Visual Studio 2015

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 , my project is having SSRS Reports Previously project was in the 2012 and everything was working .when I upgrade my project to 2015 it is showing Reporting is Incompatible .

Till now i have installed SSDT For VS2015 but i am not able to find SSDT-BI For Reports.

where i will get the BI For the Vs-2015 for download

Thank you.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541279/ssrs-missing-in-visual-studio-2015-community-enterprise-trial-version-templa/35559706#35559706)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the SSDT from the Below link

[Link SSDT](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/F/E1F25A45-8945-4197-B718-4A6DB7B4EC11/Dev14/EN/SSDTSetup.exe)

it will update the SSRS and SSIS on the Visual studio 2015 but you need internet connection. 
other Wise you have to Download the ISO file below Given Link

[Link For ISO file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/mt429383)  ISO file i never try yet i select the option online Update

and we don't have to install the SSRS BI for the Visual Studio 2015